# Any fetch to a url is triggering an additional GET request to it

Tags: javascript, sveltekit

When I fetch with any method (`POST`, `DELETE`, etc), on any url, an additional `GET` request gets triggered on said url. This is a problem in the case of a `DELETE /items/:id` which followed by a `GET /items/:id` causes an error because it tries to process the related svelte page with `undefined` as the input data.

I tried with several pages and several methods, with `console.log`s at the beginning of endpoints, this behavior is always the same.

I have no hook and I don't reload the page after requests. All my `fetch` calls are contained within functions that can only be called via events on the DOM, so nothing is on the script's root.

Here's an example of a `DELETE` endpoint (I'm mainly testing against this one) :

```js
export const DELETE = async ({params}) => {
  await meta.findOneAndDelete({url: params.url})
  return {}
}
```

It even occurs with this :

```js
export const POST = async () => {
  return {}
}
```

I call this endpoint with a `fetch(/items/${url}, {method: 'POST'})` behind a click event, and it triggers a `GET /items/:url` everytime. I should point out that these `GET` requests are not visible in the dev tools, I only see the `console.log`s I put in the `GET` endpoints and the potential errors on the server console.

Comment: It seems the endpoints return a redirect to their referrer header. Please check your server code about that.

Comment: @CherryDT I added an example endpoint in the question. Also, I did misunderstood the problem, the additional GET request is triggered on the same url, not the client's, I edited the question accordingly and I apologize for that.

Comment: Please use your devtools to check what headers are returned from the first request, and check the originator column of the second (hovering shows the stack).

Comment: @CherryDT I've added a paragraph to the question to address this : nothing is visible on the client. Errors are just happening after requests on the server and don't actually break the application (for instance the DELETE request deletes properly, an error is thrown on the server because of the GET without data, and the client is fine).

Comment: It's not possible that nothing is visible on the client. There are requests sent and responses received. In the network tab of the devtools, they create entries which log the request and response headers and data, as well as the originator (with stack) of the request. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1gAyQuIFQo

Comment: @CherryDT What if the endpoint in triggered from something else, not a request on the client ? Sorry but I do know how HTTP and the network tab work. I surely don't know what's going on, but I do know that nothing is visible on the client.
What is most likely to me is that the request is both sent and received on the server, unless the GET endpoints are triggered in another way.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like these endpoints redirect to GET /items, probably to make them work nicely with HTML forms (which is funny for DELETE endpoint, since forms only support GET and POST).

You can use `redirect` option in your `fetch` call:

```js
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    redirect: 'manual',
});
```

This will automatically cancel the following request.

Comment: Sadly, it does not work. I also tried with 'error' but nothing changed.

Comment: Are you sure that GET endpoint is being redirected to? Maybe your code requests it explicitly?

Comment: I didn't mention it being redirected, all I known is that these GET endpoints get triggered and they're not requested nor called in any way in the code.

Comment: Check in dev tools what requested them.